# Choose yuy2 or MJPEG in V4L

Tags: mjpeg, v4l2, v4l

I am implementing a Camera Preview application. I am using V4L and until now I basically use this code> https://linuxtv.org/downloads/v4l-dvb-apis/capture-example.html

In this example, or any other example I found for that matter, I could not find a possibility to change the frame format to MJPEG to get a higher fps rate. Is there a way to tell V4L to use MJPEG instead of YUY2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, it is actually pretty simple. Just change the pixelformat in the format struct to V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG.
So

```
format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_YUYV;
```

becomes

```
format.fmt.pix.pixelformat = V4L2_PIX_FMT_MJPEG;
```